# how to disable Nagle algorithm on TCP connection on iPhone

Tags: iphone, sockets, tcp, nsstream

I'm building a socket , using

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                       (CFStringRef) yourHostAsNSString,
                                       yourPortAsInteger,
                                       &myReadStream,
                                       &myWriteStream);
```

and I see that when I send a messages with "myWriteStream" it concatenate few message together and then send them.
I think it happens because of the Nagle algorithm and I want to disable it.
Does any one knows how to do it?

Answer (score 6):

No guarantee this will fix your problem, but if you want to disable the Nagle algorithm, you need to get the native socket from the stream and call `setsockopt`.

```
CFDataRef nativeSocket = CFWriteStreamCopyProperty(myWriteStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle);
CFSocketNativeHandle *sock = (CFSocketNativeHandle *)CFDataGetBytePtr(nativeSocket);
setsockopt(*sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int));
CFRelease(nativeSocket);
```

(Shout out to Mike Ash for the [compound literal](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-02-18-compound-literals.html) trick.)

Comment: +1 Great! Where did you insert this code? Right after CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost I get a BAD_EXEC because the native socket is not already initiated.

Comment: If you're working at the CFNetwork level, call `CFWriteStreamOpen` first. The connection doesn't exist until open of the streams is opened. If your streams are NSStreams, use `-[NSStream open]`.

Comment: I had to `#import <netinet/tcp.h>` for the TCP_NODELAY define. You could of course already have this in there depending on what else you're doing.

Comment: you'll also need to `#import <netinet/in.h> for the `IPPROTO_TCP` define and the `setsockopt` call itself

Comment: If you're using NSStreams, you can't get the native socket directly after `-[NSStream open]`. You have to wait until your delegate receives `NSStreamEventOpenCompleted` via `stream:handleEvent:`.

Comment: I tried this in the delegate callback stream:handleEvent but still get nil back from WriteStreamCopyProperty ?