# Setting TCP_NODELAY for NSOutputStream in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, networking, nsstream

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148059/how-to-disable-nagle-algorithm-on-tcp-connection-on-iphone) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810373/disable-nagles-algorithm-for-nsoutputstream) both show how to set `TCP_NODELAY` for `NSOutputStream` in `Objective-C`. I need some help on getting this to work in `Swift`, and I believe that it's probably just a mistake I'm making with the `API`.

This is the `Objective-C` solution that supposedly works:

```
CFDataRef nativeSocket = CFWriteStreamCopyProperty(`myWriteStream`, kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle);
CFSocketNativeHandle *sock = (CFSocketNativeHandle *)CFDataGetBytePtr(nativeSocket);
setsockopt(*sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int));
CFRelease(nativeSocket);
```

This is my attempt at translating it into `Swift`:

```
let nativeSocket: CFDataRef = CFWriteStreamCopyProperty(myWriteStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle).data
let sock = CFSocketNativeHandle(CFDataGetBytePtr(nativeSocket).memory)
var one = Int(1)
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &one, UInt32(sizeofValue(one)))
```

The real issue is getting a `CFDataRef` from `myWriteStream` (an `NSOutputStream`), and then getting a `CFSocketNativeHandle` from that.  In the `Swift` code above, it always crashes on the first line while trying to create `nativeSocket` (specifically, trying to access the `data` property).

Can somebody help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so after a while I figured it out.  Here's the working code in case somebody else needs it:

```
let socketData = CFWriteStreamCopyProperty(self.outputStream!, kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle) as! CFData
let handle = CFSocketNativeHandle(CFDataGetBytePtr(socketData).memory)
var one: Int = 1
let size = UInt32(sizeofValue(one))
setsockopt(handle, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &one, size)
```